# Is it possible to advertise on local network via Adsense?

Tags: php, networking, adsense, ads

Recently I have developed an app on php, which will be running in my workplace local network. The traffic on the Sever(hosted externally) is very large. But the problem is that, since it has to run within local network, the same public IP will be allocated to every user within the network.

Map of the network

Server (Public IP eg. 11.11.11.11) -> Local network users (eg 198.162.1.1).

My application server is has been hosted externally.

Will I be able to run advertisements(adsense) and get paid through it. As the users will always have same public IP.

Note: I am much more concerned about adsense(by google).

I would also like to know the best way to earn through a social networking site other then addsense.

I request you to answer descriptively.Feel free to edit this question for better understanding.Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Yes, because in your case even google.com will be browsed from local network and so it will also have traffic. Now just don't ask your friends to click on adds in your website.***

First, here’s a very brief outline of exactly how AdSense works:
You sign up for AdSense with Google, and, if you are accepted, Google will start placing ads on your web pages automatically.
If someone on your site sees an ad and clicks on it they leave your site.
Google charges the advertiser for the click and shares this money with you. This type of advertising is called Pay Per Click advertising, usually abbreviated to PPC.
The Ads you get on your web pages are usually relevant to your visitor.

With a planned $90 million settlement, Google could soon dispense with a class-action lawsuit involving so-called click fraud.
But while that may be good for Google, it doesn't mean the problem of bogus clicks on online ads--which advertisers have to pay for--is going to disappear anytime soon. A lack of clear standards for determining what is a fraudulent click, or some sort of third-party clearinghouse to monitor the situation, means some advertisers believe they can't do much more than head to the courts when they think there's a problem.
Certainly, Google and Yahoo, which run the two largest pay-per-click advertising networks, say they're addressing the problem. But some click auditing companies still claim that between 20 percent and 35 percent of clicks on Net advertisements are fraudulent.
Unfortunately, there's no easy answer. Some experts say the solution is to have an independent auditor that would use data from the search engines and advertisers to determine in a neutral environment whether clicks are fraudulent.

**I repeat, in your case users will even browse google.com or other site, which enables them to know the network type that you have. But make don't click on your own adds which violates their TOS.** All the best.

Answer (score 1):

i think it is not possible to run in local network because i should hit the Google adsense server so that it increases your earnings. you can let your Google adsense Script run it doesn't consume more bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say no.

For a better, more descriptive answer, [ask Adsense directly](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=adsense&ltmpl=adsense&continue=https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/17470?hl=en&continue=https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/17470%3Fhl%3Den)

**Possible related questions**

- [Intranet Ads? Same IP, multiple hits](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense-help-guidelines/BPl1uUDVCCM)
- [How google adsense detects that the clicks are made from same computer ? Do they check ip addresses ?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100211015008AAWwBZ2)
- [Is it legal to add google adsense acount to Local LAN website?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/7nn-2h7diFs)

**Edit for 1st comment**

> would you mind giving some conclusion explaining briefly. Can you also give some good alternative to google adsense for a social networking site. I appreciate for help

As all clickouts will be on the same IP "*As the users will always have same public IP.*", Google will think this is "clickfraud", and you're falsifying authentic clickouts - which you're not, but this is what it will seem like, on Google's end.

Google will first flag your account, and then (most likely, after investigating) close your Adsense account.

Alternatives to Adsense would be;

- Infolinks
- Kontera
- Amazon Associates
- BuySellAds
- Text Link Ads
- Clicksor

  - Apparently a good choice
- Adversal

I've not used any of these personally, and I fetched this list from [stream-seo.com](http://stream-seo.com/best-google-adsense-alternatives/)

Comment: would you mind giving some conclusion explaining briefly. Can you also give some good alternative to google adsense for a social networking site. I appreciate for help

Comment: Updated answer :) Also, after more investigation, I changed my answer from yes, to no.